# Connection Refused when trying to download file from Sharepoint

Tags: java, sharepoint

I am trying to download a .xlsx file via the following Java code:

```
InputStream input = new URL("https://some.example-website.com/path/to/the/file.xlsx").openStream();
```

**This .xlsx file is on a Sharepoint website.**

If I visit the URL directly in my browser it will download the file automatically in Chrome so I'm confused as to why when I run the above code from my machine I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I am looking for a way to download and save this .xlsx file using a tool written in Java ran from my machine.

Comment: You must setup the credentials

Comment: Even though I am already logged in from the machine I am running it from?